# Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date doesn't work with get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, angularjs-filter

I have an UTC date which I am passing to Angular's date filter to convert it to local time zone after submitting form and still in the same page like bellow :

```
 $scope.XService.update($scope.Id, $scope.model).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.addAlert("success", "Opération terminée avec succès");

                        var mydate1 = data.StartDateTimeUtc;
                        var mydate2 = data.EndDateTimeUtc;
                        data.StartDateTimeUtc = $filter('date')(new Date(mydate1), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
                        data.EndDateTimeUtc = $filter('date')(new Date(mydate2), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
                        $scope.model = data;
                        alert($scope.model.PublishStartDateTimeUtc); 
                       alert($scope.model.PublishEndDateTimeUtc);

                    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.addAlert("danger", data);
                    });
```

This work for me very well , the dates are converted to local time zone But my problem is that this converting code doesn't work for me in the 
    get method like bellow :

```
$scope.XService.get($scope.Id).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var mydate1 = $scope.model.StartDateTimeUtc;
            var mydate2 = $scope.model.EndDateTimeUtc;
            $scope.model.StartDateTimeUtc = $filter('date')(new Date(mydate1), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
            $scope.model.EndDateTimeUtc = $filter('date')(new Date(mydate2), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');

            $scope.model = data;

               alert($scope.model.EndDateTimeUtc); alert($scope.model.StartDateTimeUtc);
            console.info("advertisning model", $scope.model);
            $scope.model.Id = $scope.AdvertisementId;
            $scope.newCreate = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }
```

It return the UTC dates saved in BD , What could be the problem??

Comment: This code is not clear to me:
Why is the XService reference sitting on the $scope object?
It looks like there is some mixup between the service and the model values...

Comment: @Danny R  I edit my code to clear it. I used the Xservice to get and submit my form from it to consume a web api method

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting the $scope.model object after assigning the date filter values

Comment: @DannyR yes i'm overwriting the $scope.model object to convert the dates coming from BD with utc value to my local zone after submitting form it sucessed but after gettinf form it doesn't